# Google colab : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymorphy2'

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

Im doing my project in university using Morphological Analyzer of text(russian language).Google Colab cant find the module named pymorphy2.
`from pymorphy2 import MorphAnalyzer`
Maybe there are sollutions for such problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to pip install it?

Write this and execute the cell:

```
!pip install pymorphy2
```